# RDP suddenly stop working on 2 servers and 1 laptop

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, rdp

we have like 10 servers (running as DC for each site), also some workstations/laptop working on each site. We use RDP to admin every DC server. This structure was working nice and well, BUT...

Today we have 2 servers (running Windows Server 2012 R2 full updated) that can't be accessed by RDP. We tried to diagnose the problem, this is the list of thing we checked:

- Reboot the servers
- Connect using `mstsc` and `mstsc /admin` using DNS name and IP
- Check that `Terminal Server` service is up and running (we also restarted that service), also we disabled/enabled the service again.
- Firewall is diabled
- Ping is working OK, we have connectivity, we can access SMB shares for example...
- HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber have 3389 value
- We generated a new certificate for Remote Desktop (using Certificates mmc console)

But we can't connect to the servers using RDP. We checked again the remote servers:

- RDP is not listening
- `netstat -an | findstr 3389` shows nothing
- `qwinsta` dosn't show any RDP-TCP connection
- There is no visible eventlog in EventViewer
- `chkdsk /R` didn't solved the issue
- `sfc /scannow` didn't solved the issue

This is the error we get after trying to RDP on that servers:

[image]

Can somebody help us with this issue? We tried every google-search-solution, without success

Comment: I know you checked the terminal services but did you check that the RDP settings are under system properties. I would disable RDP and reenable it not the service but the config. I would also check that no GPO or local security policy is messing up your RDP settings. Try using RSOP.msc I would also check the remote desktop services manager on the servers and the registry settings for RDP make sure everything is correct.

Answer (score 0):

So the 2 servers in question are Domain Controllers... Can you move the computer object from it's current location to the top level - OU=Computers

Then refresh group policy.
Use rsop.msc to check before / after behaviour

As for re-configuring/installing the Remote Desktop Protocol (Terminal Server).  I would try:

- System Properties, Remote Tab, Don't allow
- Backup and then delete registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer
- Reboot
- Allow remote connections again. Check registry has re-created keys

Server Manager

- Does it show remote desktop as enabled?
- Any NIC teaming on these servers
- Any multi ip addr
- Any windows update driver changes to NIC

Do you have no output of these commands?

```
netstat -an -o | findstr 3389
TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       2144
TCP    192.168.9.35:3389      ??.??.???.???:50144    ESTABLISHED     2144
TCP    [::]:3389              [::]:0                 LISTENING       2144
UDP    0.0.0.0:3389           *:*                                    2144
UDP    [::]:3389              *:*                                    2144
```

and

```
netstat -an -b | findstr TermService
TermService
TermService
TermService 
TermService
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a migrating a Windows Server 2008R2 (p2v), my resolution may work for you:

The problem occurs because the RDP service tries to use the old network adapter.

After some hours of google, I found this option in registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server\WinStations\RDP-Tcp
```

Change the `LanAdapter` value from **`1`** to **`0`**, to allow RDP in all network adapters.

Reboot the system and test.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I edited the registry key to format it as code, that helps avoid copy/paste errors. Also the options, so they are clearer. You can use the backticks (`) or the code {} button in the editor. This removes format.